# ask browser to probe data on another site

Tags: javascript, web, browser, cross-domain, cross-site

Imagine I own MySite.com and I want to crowdsource uptime monitoring of OtherSite.com.

when Alice visits MySite.com I want to ask her browser to send a request to OtherSite.com and then report back to MySite.com if the request to OtherSite.com succeeded or failed.

if this method is possible, I can basically do uptime monitoring without having a backend.

is it possible to write a JS/HTML hosted on MySite.com that achieves this? or is it blocked by cross-site scripting or other blocking mechanisms?
code example?

Answer (score 1):

It's blocked by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), unless of course OtherSite.com whitelists all origins via `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.

What you *could* do is have OtherSite.com host script or image with no caching, and have MySite.com request that file via a `script` element or `img` element. If the request succeeds, OtherSite.com is up; if not, OtherSite.com is down (or at least not serving that file). You can't read the *content* of the script/image, because that would violate the SOP, but you can detect success or failure loading it.

Of course, you'll still need some means of aggregating this information, which suggests the need for *some* kind of backend.

Comment: any white hat way to bypass that without changes to OtherSite.com ?

Comment: Just the above (second paragraph), but the above should do the trick. The bigger issue is the third paragraph (just added). :-)